# Android Studio Download Archive

Tags: android

Windows 11 Pro. Android Studio download archives. I try to download Arctic Fox patch 4 for a class I wish to take. I can download the windows.executable  file with no problem except that the finished downloaded file is not executable. The file does not download as a .executable file. Actually any of the archive files downloaded are missing the .executable extension and will not install. I downloaded the zip file,extracted the file to a new folder. I opened the Bin Folder - and clicked the 64.executable file or what ever it was and just receive a Arctic Fox splash screen, no installation. Read some where that I needed Java on Wind0ws 11 so I installed Java
So what is going on?? Why won't the files download properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the link using 'save link as' option and verify if the file's extension is .exe . This happens if a file is not completely downloaded due to internet issues or the file extension is lost while renaming the file. Also try opening the executable file from the bin folder using the 'Run as administrator' option of windows which will be shown when right clicking on the file itself. Going to the file location using terminal and trying to open the executable using terminal is also an option to try. This will give you an insight of the issue if some logs are showing up in the terminal.